# URL for the named route "lightsaml.login_check"

Tags: symfony, azure-active-directory, symfony4, saml, saml-2.0

I try a login my application Symfony 4.3 with AzureAD.  I have following the Getting Started(https://www.lightsaml.com/SP-Bundle/Getting-started/) but he doesn't work !

He show me this error `Unable to generate a URL for the named route "lightsaml.login_check"`

I don't know how fix this !

Someone can help me please :/

Comment: It seems that there is no route for `lightsaml.login_check` maybe she doesn't have the same name. 

Try the command `bin/console debug:route`. It will display all route availables with theirs names. You will maybe find the right route name to use.

Comment: the lightsaml bundle apparently was designed for symfony <= 3.3. in 4.4 bundles are registered in config/bundles.php if I recall correctly. However, I can't tell if the lightsaml bundle even works with symfony 4.x